# mvc option with html content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

mvc option with html content

how to write/render

```html
 <select>
      <option><span style="">Hi</span></option>
      <option><span style="">Hi1</span></option>
      <option><span style="">Hi2</span></option>
</select>
```

using @html.DropDownList()

--------Update-------------

i want to use html formatted text in option
when i passed it from modal, it was showing in dropdown list

```html
<span style="">Hi</span>
<span style="">Hi1</span>
<span style="">Hi2</span>
```

here the span style="" is html it is not string, and the list is coming from controller

Comment: why it is down voting? did i ask something wrong

Comment: please check and edit your question, we don't understand question.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Use SelectItem in the code, insert options in that list, provide another property for selected item on Post using passing it to the view and use @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectItem) a simple example can be

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Package.State, new SelectList(
              new List<Object>{ 
                   new { value = 0 , text = "Red"  },
                   new { value = 1 , text = "Blue" },
                   new { value = 2 , text = "Green"}
                },
              "value",
              "text",
               2))
```